# Why is the "this" value different?

Tags: javascript, this

Here is an example where `o.foo();` is 3 but `(p.foo = o.foo)();` is 2?

```js
function foo() {
    console.log( this.a );
}

var a = 2;
var o = { a: 3, foo: foo };
var p = { a: 4 };

o.foo(); // 3
(p.foo = o.foo)(); // 2”
```

If I do something like this then I get `4` which is what I want. How are those 2 examples are different?

```
p.foo = o.foo;
p.foo();  // 4
```

Comment: Do you mean `o.foo()` returns `{a: 3, foo: ƒ}` ?

Comment: @UladKasach sorry ment `console.log( this.a );` edited my code

Comment: That's because you are using a self-invoking function. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592396/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-self-executing-function-in-javascript)

Comment: @AlexandreMiziara - Are you sure this is an IIFE?  And if it is, how does that explain the result?

Comment: When you do p.foo = o.foo. You are trying to assign two unequal objects (one has more properties than the other). Then on top of that you call () at the end which commands the function to invoke immediately. Naturally that would cause some issues

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth, I believe it is. A self-invoking function runs automatically/immediately when you create it, so `foo` will print the value of the variable `a` that was already defined on the scope.

Comment: @AlexandreMiziara - But (a) the function isn't being created there, and (b) why would that affect the scoping rules?

Comment: @AlexandreMiziara that is not what people generally mean by IIFE.  It's a function invocation, but the left-hand side is not a function definition expression. However, that's just a pedantic opinion-based usage note and I invite you to use the term however you like :)

Comment: @Pointy I'm sorry I haven't cleary saw that. The left side is not an anonymous function, so according to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) that really isn't a IIFE. Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth so what I said is most likely not the cause of the problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This :

```
(p.foo = o.foo)();
```

Is pretty much the same as doing this:

```
d = (p.foo = o.foo);
d();
```

Basically what it says is that the return of an assignment is the function itself in the global context. On which `a` is 2.

Answer (score 4):

Performing that assignment operation before the function call here:

```
(p.foo = o.foo)();
```

causes the object reference to `p` to be lost. If you instead wrote

```
p.foo = o.foo;
p.foo();
```

you'd get 4. As it is, you get 2 because the value of `this` will be `window` in the function.

Because that parenthesized subexpression is an assignment result, there's no object lookup directly associated with the result of the expression — the value of the assignment expression is *just* the function reference without a contextual object. Thus the runtime doesn't have a value to use for `this` when it calls the function, so `this` is bound by default to `window` (or the global object in whatever context).

Comment: hold on I think that explanation is wrong ...

Comment: "*The ( ) creates a subexpression "layer" that causes the object association to be dropped.*" - It must be more complicated than that, though.  `(o.foo)();` works fine.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth yes that's what I realized because a dim memory was making me think I'd definitely used parentheses in cases vaguely (but not exactly) like this; see edit.

Comment: I find that kind of odd. Why is it that p gets lost instead of o? Isn't o the r_value operand?

Comment: @Callat see edit; the original explanation in the last paragraph was me typing before thinking clearly.

Answer (score 4):

actually your code is wrong because your snippet doesnt run, you should be doing the following: `console.log( this.a );`

and now, lets see how this works.

```
function foo() {
    console.log( this.a );
}
```

this will call `this` in the scope of the caller, so lets investigate our results.

so, you are setting `a=2` globally, and then in the objects `o.a = 3` and `p.a=4`

so:

calling  `o.foo` it will return `3` because this is pointing to `o`

calling  `p.foo` it will return `4` because this is pointing to `p`

BUT

calling  `(p.foo = o.foo)();` it will return `2` because it is not pointing to any object, so it will take your scope (which is the global scope) and then it will return `2`.

if you go with:

```
p.foo = o.foo
p.foo() //4
```

it will return 4 successfully because it is pointing to `p`.

Comment: Already changed my code to `console.log( this.a );` thanks =)

Comment: @AlexeyTseitlin yeah, I noticed after writing my answer, hope it was helpful